# How would you sharpen nasal scissors?

Tags: repair

I've got a rather old pair of nasal scissors which has gone blunt over time. I'd like to sharpen them again as where I live you can only get those huge, pricey equipment packs that come with a lot of stuff you'd never really need.

How could, if possible, nasal scissors be sharpened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out! For anyone who's curious, here's **how to sharpen nasal scissors**.

---

You will need:
 1. a sort-of-rough edge (the glass panel of a modern digital weighing scale did the trick for me)
[image: This edge.]

2. something to test the scissors on (preferably not nasal keratin. I used cardboard rolls)

---

Firstly, check your scissors and note the which side the cutting edge is facing. Most scissors have a small slope. This is the part we want to sharpen, as this is used for cutting.

Next, press the sloping edge to the surface you intend to use for sharpening. It may be better to use the corner of the surface. With medium force, press the scissor edge to the surface and pull downwards for about five to ten centimetres.

Repeat for the other cutting edge on the scissors, and test the sharpness. If necessary, repeat the above steps, though one run was enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to cut a simple sandpaper several times with this scissors.